# Can't update Xcode 11

Tags: xcode, macos-catalina, xcode11, xcode11.1

Trying to update from Xcode 11 GM to 11.1 always fail.

I tried moving /Applications/Xcode.app first... nothing works

This is my commerce log:

> 2019-10-08 12:29:08+01 leviathan installd[556]: PackageKit: Install Failed: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=501 "The package is attempting to install content to the system volume." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The package is attempting to install content to the system volume.} {

Comment: Based on the definition "...unless they involve tools used primarily for programming."  Considering Xcode is MOST definitely a tool used specifically for programing it seem to me it's matt, Maddy, Nkosi, TyhlerH, and Zoe the transgirl who've got it wrong.

Comment: I have to agree with you there... And given that quite a few people seem to be encountering this issue (including me), I would think that it should stay open.

Comment: I had not the problem the OP reported, but updating failed to me as well. In the console many issues are reported, one of them being - not sure it's the most relevant: [UPD2929A2AC/com.apple.dt.Xcode:497799835] Blocking delta after encountering error: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=501 "Il pacchetto sta cercando di installare dei contenuti sul volume di sistema." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Il pacchetto sta cercando di installare dei contenuti sul volume di sistema.} - the solution by Mojtaba saved the day

Answer (score 81, accepted):

## Manual download

> The always working and preferred workaround!

Download directly from Apple:

- **[Latest Release version](https://developer.apple.com/download/release/)** or
- **[Latest Beta version](https://developer.apple.com/download/)** or
- **[Any version you need](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)** and all other downloadable contents

Then extract and move it where you like. This has so many benefits comparing to AppStore updates. (like the ability to resume download, not replacing the old one, not wasting hidden directories and etc.)

**Note that** you should use safari to download it.

---

## Force App Store to re-download.

Apple suggested this workaround but many developers (including me)prefer manual download to save a lot of network traffic!

Since This is [Known Issues](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_1_release_notes#3400988)

> Xcode may fail to update from the Mac App Store after updating to macOS Catalina. (56061273)

Apple suggest this:

> To trigger a new download you can delete the existing `Xcode.app` or temporarily change the file extension so it is no longer visible to the App Store.

Comment: This is good info and I was unable to find that link when logging into the developer account.  How did you find it?

Comment: Ah here we go [https://developer.apple.com/download/more/](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/).

Comment: I resort to deleting old android libraries, old xcode and left overs. This contributes my successful installation. That takes 68 GBs available on my hard disk. That only takes 10Gbs size. the Apple should clearly and correctly estimate the requirement of hard disk space

Comment: This solution, I think has the problem, that you will never get your Xcode automatically updated from the AppStore in the future. By the way, Apple itself knows that issue and they offer a solution as well, see here  ->  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_1_release_notes

Comment: removing .app extension worked for me

Comment: Why is it so difficult to Apple to fix this bug? I'm facing it since Xcode 8 all the time. :(