# Xcode not opening after updating to MacOS Catalina

Tags: ios, xcode

I updated to MacOS Catalina and now my Xcode is not opening. I get this prompt:

[image]

Which leads to this error after getting root access:

[image]

There is a huge log but the key errors are:

> 2019-11-04 12:39:48+05 tk_lpt_0141_wifi Xcode[1214]: Package:
>   PKLeopardPackage 
>   Failed to verify with error: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain
>   Code=102 "The package “MobileDeviceDevelopment.pkg” is untrusted."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The package
>   “MobileDeviceDevelopment.pkg” is untrusted.,
>   NSURL=MobileDeviceDevelopment.pkg --
>   file:///Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/,
>   PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.apple.pkg.MobileDeviceDevelopment,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe07012cad0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain
>   Code=-2147409654 "CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED" UserInfo={SecTrustResult=5,
>   PKTrustLevel=PKTrustLevelExpiredCertificate,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED}}} 2019-11-04
>
> 13:01:20+05 tk_lpt_0141_wifi Xcode[1306]: Package: PKLeopardPackage
>   
>   Failed to verify with error: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain
>   Code=102 "The package “MobileDeviceDevelopment.pkg” is untrusted."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The package
>   “MobileDeviceDevelopment.pkg” is untrusted.,
>   NSURL=MobileDeviceDevelopment.pkg --
>   file:///Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/,
>   PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.apple.pkg.MobileDeviceDevelopment,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd230cb1ae0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain
>   Code=-2147409654 "CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED" UserInfo={SecTrustResult=5,
>   PKTrustLevel=PKTrustLevelExpiredCertificate,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED}}} 2019-11-04
>
> 13:29:51+05 tk_lpt_0141_wifi Xcode[1377]: Package: PKLeopardPackage
>   
>   Failed to verify with error: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain
>   Code=102 "The package “MobileDeviceDevelopment.pkg” is untrusted."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The package
>   “MobileDeviceDevelopment.pkg” is untrusted.,
>   NSURL=MobileDeviceDevelopment.pkg --
>   file:///Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/,
>   PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.apple.pkg.MobileDeviceDevelopment,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8ab8ba9380 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain
>   Code=-2147409654 "CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED" UserInfo={SecTrustResult=5,
>   PKTrustLevel=PKTrustLevelExpiredCertificate,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED}}}

I have already tried:

```
xcode-select --install
```

and

```
xcode-select --reset
```

Has anyone else run into this issue? How to fix it?

Comment: What version of Xcode?

Comment: @trojanfoe 11. It was fixed with Vinod's solution below

Comment: 11 isn't the latest version though.  Also what version of Catalina as 10.15.0 isn't the latest either.  It's important to give version details for these types of questions.  Also changing your clock to fix an issue is a massive hack.

Comment: The official Apple solution can be found in an answer to an earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58550284/mobiledevice-pkg-untrusted-cannot-open-xcode-after-os-x-update/58598570#58598570):

Answer (score 90, accepted):

**First, try updating Xcode through the app store**

As a last resort, you can change your MacOS Date to

```
1st October 2019
```

I set my system time to `1st October 2019,` the date when the certificate was still valid. Then, I opened Xcode and followed the component install. This went well, and now Xcode works again.

Edit and set the date of your Mac as `1st October 2019`.

Comment: That date thing works. Damn, Apple ... ‍♂️

Comment: After changing the system time I couldn't change it back, because I lost my sudo rights. I also couldn't open any https website, because the browser said, that my clock is behind. And I couldn't install the components, because the system didn't accept my password anymore. So be warned! This workaround only works if you have root access on your workplace computer.

Comment: Xcode 11.2 was released on 31st October 2019. Why would there be a need to set the clock 1 month prior to the release?

Comment: due to CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED resultant com.apple.softwareupdated was invalidated @Cœur

Comment: Not a recommended solution, it can cause more issues. Updating via the App Store is the only valid answer.

Comment: You can update your system time again for actual. @SergeLiberloo

Comment: macOS (software in general) doesn't like the system clock changing very much. It plays havoc with anything that has a cache and secure systems like keychain. Here's what I did: create an admin user account on your mac, log out of your account, and do the system time trick as that new admin user. Then, once the components are installed, set the clock back, log back in as your main user and delete the temporary admin account. Done!

Comment: Love the trick. I'll try to do the same while checking for Apple Care expiration! :D

Comment: I can't believe it

Comment: Baffling this worked. But unsurprised given most of my most recent Apple developer experiences

Comment: this was the solution..

i have sierra 10.13.6.

Comment: and they wonder why we developers hate Mac. Thanks

Answer (score 16):

What worked for me was updating Xcode in the App Store. After that I was able to install the additional components successfully.

Comment: I try to avoid changing my clock since it has caused other problems in the past. I 
 installed Xcode from the App Store, launched, installed components, done. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Indeed the only valid answer to this issue. It would have been nice is Xcode made this suggestion itself when this error occurs.

Comment: I can't update Xcode from the app store, it downloads the full 7GB or so and then runs through the same 'additional components' install problem.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is not a good idea to change your system clock if you don't need to.

Comment: Many developers have more than one version of XCode installed for a variety of necessary reasons.  It's not all about updating to the latest version of XCode.  If we could all support all iOS software and devices from the latest version of XCode life would be simple.